# What does the +/- dial in the Lego Defender model do?

Tags: technic, sets, gearing

Lego today [released a video](https://youtu.be/smampJ2MIhU) showcasing the new 42110 Land Rover Defender model.

The video captions mention that it has “Lego Technic’s most sophisticated gearbox to date”, and we see 3 seemingly related features.

The first two are fairly typical levers for “hi/lo” and “?/N/R”, ie gear selection and direction.

The other is a dial labelled “+ -“:

[image]

What is this dial for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a comment found in the overview on Brickset, and that all of the others levers and their function seem to be accounted for, it seem very likely that it is the transmission gear selector.

-UPDATE BELOW-

From Brickset:

> "A new transmission system has two levers for engaging high or low
>   ratios and a selector for changing gear – LEGO Technic’s most
>   sophisticated gearbox yet."

Source: https://brickset.com/article/45677/introducing-the-technic-land-rover-defender

In other words, the transmission gears 1-?, rather than it's selection D/N/R and transfer case Hi/Lo.  The transmission looks too complicated to just be directional switch (D/N/R) and 1 gear range switch (Hi/Lo).

[image]
[image]

I have no idea how many gears it has, or if I am even correct.  It's all just speculation based on my observations.  Either way the set looks amazing!  I'm a sucker for vintage cars and all things 4x4.

Just confirmed from Lego.com:

> Opening doors allow access to an elaborate cabin with a working
>   steering wheel, detailed dashboard and a new-for-October-2019
>   transmission system with 2 levers for engaging high or low gear ratios
>   and a selector for changing gear – the most sophisticated LEGO Technic
>   gearbox to date! The interior also features forward-folding rear seats
>   that give visual access to the 4-speed sequential gearbox.
>   https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/land-rover-defender-42110

So it's a 4-speed transmission, nice!

Comment: Wow! I didn’t think it could be anything like that due to the ease with which it appears to rotate!

Comment: @JamesThorpe - Maybe a worm gear type setup?  Lego continues to amaze me with the complexity of their sets.

Comment: Could be - one of the stills you selected from the video [has this orange piece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YFz3.png) in it - looks to be a way of activating the neighbouring gear lock via rotation rather than the usual reciprocation of a lever

Comment: I assume it's [one of these](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=35188#T=C&C=4) - seems it's also been in the Bugatti last year.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - I honestly didn't even know that existed.  The Bugatti has yet to be squeezed into the budget.  Now I'm all sorts of curious about the transmission in that thing.

Comment: I'd forgotten about its paddle shift until I looked again earlier - now I'm wondering about the innards of that gearbox too...

Comment: The actual designer of the set [has an overview here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3DPvbhjX-M). Skip to 1:24 for the innards...!  (The +/- is _definitely_ gear change!)

Comment: @JamesThorpe - Nice!  Thanks for the link :)